# Parsing JSON in android using Volley and StringRequest

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a JSON object to listview in android.

```
       final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data..");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {

                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                        for (int i=0; i<= array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                    o.getString("name"),
                                    o.getString("realname"),
                                    o.getString("team"),
                                    o.getString("firstappearance"),
                                    o.getString("createdby"),
                                    o.getString("publisher"),
                                    o.getString("imageurl"),
                                    o.getString("bio")
                            );
                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            , new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

This is the function i am using to parse JSON using volley.
App is running and no error was thrown but the view was empty and when i used static data instead of JSON the data was displayed in expected format.

JSON link is https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/marvel/index.php

Comment: can't see your json

Comment: call .notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter

Comment: Doesn't work for me .. since when i pass a list with data definate data than output is there while this code does not parse any data from the link so i believe there might be some error in this code only

Comment: is your progress dialog dismissing?  can you able to log String s?

Comment: my progress dialog dismiss after few seconds and after that there is nothing visible on the panel